# std::ostringstream to LPCSTR?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, std, lpcstr

How can I convert a `std::ostringstream` to `LPCSTR`?

```
std::ostringstream oss;
[...]
LPCSTR result = oss.str();
```

Result: `Error: No suitable conversion function from "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" to "LPCSTR" exists`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
std::string str = oss.str();
LPCSTR cstr = str.c_str();
```

Note that you `cstr` only remains valid until the next modification of `str`. So you cannot, for instance, return `cstr` from a function because `str` is a local variable that has left scope.

Instead of returning `LPCSTR` from this function, return `std::string`. That avoids dealing with lifetime issues if you returned `LPCSTR`. If you returned `LPCSTR` you would have to allocate memory and make sure you deallocated it. Exactly the sort of thing you don't want to be doing in C++ code. So, return `std::string` and call `c_str()` on that object at the point where you call the Windows API function.

Comment: Returning it was exactly what I was planning to do, so how could I do that?

Comment: Don't do that. It will leave you with all sorts of lifetime headaches. Return a `std::string` and call `c_str()` on that at the point where you need to call the winapi function.

Comment: Returning a reference to a local isn't going to end well. Don't hand out dead cows (or objects in general).

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, you are quite right. Comment and answer edited.